# Проблема с PNG файлом

Tags: android, png

Ошибки в logcat:

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>   glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401

При запуске приложения в эмуляторе выскакивает ошибка *Unfortunatelly,has stopped.*

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за RGB профиля сохраненного в PNG файле, возьмите утилиту [PNGCrush](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush) и запустите на свой PNG файл нечто вроде:

```
pngcrush -ow -rem allb -reduce myfile.png
```

[Пруфлинк](https://gist.github.com/rupakraj/5e7e58a666282ca9c2f7)

Comment: Так и не понял, что мне следует сделать?